# How to modify my store information on Google search?

Tags: google-search, google-maps, google-my-business

I have recently made a blog for my store, and I want to link it to my physical store, which is already registered on Google Maps. My desired result is that my store would go up in search ranking on Google Maps as I grow my website. How do I modify my store's information?

For your information, my store's name is sinar maju lighting. It's located at Palembang, Indonesia.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/resarch efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Tip: Learn about https://business.google.com

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to google my business
2. Find your store
3. Claim
4. If said store is claimed, request ownership
5. wait 7 days
6. If appeal is neglected, ask for approval. Google will provide a form as authentication for your store